# Hats hats hats hats... - clarification for upvote hats

Tags: discussion, winterbash

I have some questions about hats. Unfortunately [a certain badp likes abusing me](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/5641/revisions), so I will raise them as separate questions.

When it says *X upvoted Y* (X = number, Y = "questions" or "answers") does this mean X Y's with upvotes, or X upvotes on Y?

Hat hat hat... ahem, Ho ho ho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the former, you need that many questions or answers that are upvoted. For hitting specific scores, that would be the following set of hats that says "question/answer score X+".